# firestore createquery filter give error "9 FAILED_PRECONDITION: no matching index found"

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloned production environment and firestore db. I have the following code running OK in production:

```
const query = Datastore.datastore.createQuery('users').filter('email', '=', email);
const results = await Datastore.datastore.runQuery(query);
```

In my dev environment, however, I got an error: "9 FAILED_PRECONDITION: no matching index found."

I cloned and restored the firestore db in my dev using npm firestore-backup-restore. I have verified that the data that I am looking for exist by querying directly from https://console.firebase.google.com and got the expected result.

In my dev environment, I have the same composite index as the one in production and there is no exemption in the single field index.

Is there some sort of configuration that I missed? How do I run manual indexing?

Thanks in advance.